# Как сверстать этот элемент

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите, как бы вы сверстали элемент,рука со смартфоном,я новичок не могу понять лучше сделать его background'ом или img ?Если бэкграундом ,то к какому элементу привязывать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]GG0.png

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сами Вы что сделали для реализации задачи? За вас тут никто ничего делать не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно мыслите. Лучше фоном у основного блока, а текст внутри него пусть прыгает в зависимости от ширины экрана. Тем более на этом сайте все так и сделано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо,а  не можете поделиться ссылкой ?:)

Comment: http://anna-v.github.io/pink/